# Not all threads finish their work (files downloaded are corrupted, not downloaded entirely)

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to download files - using python threading module - from Web. All URLs are stored in text file - urls.txt. My python script works, but not all files are downloaded entirely, most not - they are "corrupt".

Looks like, not all threads finish their work.

How can I fix this problem?

**Here is python script:**

```
import threading
import requests
from os import path


DIRECTORY = "DATA"
urls = None


def download(link, idx):
    file_name = "my_file-" + str(idx) + ".pdf"
    file_name = path.join(DIRECTORY, file_name)
    print("\n URL -> ", link)
    print("\n FN -> ", file_name)
    try:
        r = requests.get(link, stream=True)
        with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
            for chunk in r.iter_content(1024):
                if chunk:
                    f.write(chunk)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e.with_traceback())


def create_new_download_thread(link, idx):
    download_thread = threading.Thread(target=download, args=(link, idx,))
    return download_thread


with open('urls.txt', 'r') as f:
    urls = f.readlines()

print(len(urls))
threads = list()
for i, url in enumerate(urls):
    print("\n i= ", i)
    t = create_new_download_thread(url, i)
    threads.append(t)

for t in threads:
    t.start()

for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

I also add my txt file for faster use and try:

**urls.txt**

```
http://www.open3d.org/paper.pdf
http://www.bodden.de/pubs/kps+21qualitative.pdf
http://proceedings.esri.com/library/userconf/proc17/tech-workshops/tw_447-391.pdf
http://www.ijitee.org/wp-content/uploads/papers/v8i12S/L114510812S19.pdf
http://www.unifr.ch/appecon/en/assets/public/Lehrstuhl/Winter%20School%202022/Unboxing%20the%20Machine%20Learning%20Algorithms%20in%20Python_Christian%20Kauth.pdf
http://englishonlineclub.com/pdf/Data%20Structures%20and%20Algorithms%20in%20Python%20[EnglishOnlineClub.com].pdf
http://link.springer.com/content/pdf/bfm%3A978-1-4842-0055-1%2F1.pdf
http://www.astro.sunysb.edu/steinkirch/reviews/algorithms_in_python.pdf
http://nptel.ac.in/content/syllabus_pdf/106106145.pdf
http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/compsci105s1c/resources/ProblemSolvingwithAlgorithmsandDataStructures.pdf
http://www.leesbrook.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/sites/19/2021/08/Computer-Science-KO-Y10-Algorithms-and-Python.pdf
http://www.leesbrook.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/sites/19/2021/12/Computer-Science-3.pdf
http://jict.ilmauniversity.edu.pk/journal/jict/14.1/4.pdf
http://d1rkab7tlqy5f1.cloudfront.net/TUDelft/Onderwijs/Opleidingen/Master/MSc_Life_Science_and_Technology/Application%20and%20admission/Indicative%20entry%20level%20Algorithms%20and%20Programming.pdf
http://www.theoj.org/joss-papers/joss.03917/10.21105.joss.03917.pdf
http://cbseacademic.nic.in/web_material/Curriculum21/publication/secondary/Python_Content_Manual.pdf
http://www.ijert.org/research/python-libraries-development-frameworks-and-algorithms-for-machine-learning-applications-IJERTV7IS040173.pdf
http://raw.githubusercontent.com/mdipierro/nlib/master/docs/book_numerical.pdf
http://hal.inria.fr/hal-03100076/file/jmlr20.pdf
http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume13/fortin12a/fortin12a.pdf
http://www-s3-live.kent.edu/s3fs-root/s3fs-public/file/CS%2061002%20%20ALGORITHMS%20AND%20PROGRAMMING%20I.pdf
http://rmd.ac.in/onlinecourses/2018/oct7ecwr.pdf
http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-0001-introduction-to-computer-science-and-programming-in-python-fall-2016/lecture-slides-code/MIT6_0001F16_Lec12.pdf
http://cs-cmuq.github.io/110-www/lectures/04-algo-to-python.pdf
http://www.purdue.edu/hla/sites/varalalab/wp-content/uploads/sites/20/2018/04/Lecture_13.pdf
```

Comment: This is probably because you are not checking the HTTP response code. At least one of those URLs will return HTTP 403

Comment: One or few links might be broken, but not all. I got them from webbrowser, after googling for PDF files with python algorithms. Is it possible that one (or few) "bad" links will interrupt the whole process??

Comment: Your *download()* thread will always terminate. However, if the HTTP status code is not 200 then the response content cannot be relied upon to be meaningful in the context of what you're trying to do. Please review my Answer below for a more robust approach

Comment: "Your download() thread will always terminate" ? Terminate, because of some error?

Comment: No. It will always terminate (return None) because you try/except any potential exceptions

Comment: Now everything is clear for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

urls.txt contains exactly what you show in your question. The code:

```
import requests
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from http import HTTPStatus
from requests.exceptions import HTTPError

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.2 Safari/605.1.15'}

def change_scheme(url):
    return url.replace('http:', 'https:') if url.startswith('http:') else url.replace('https:', 'http:')

def do_get(url):
    for _ in range(2):
        try:
            (r := requests.get(url.strip(), headers=headers, stream=True)).raise_for_status()
            # process content
            break
        except HTTPError as e:
            if r.status_code != HTTPStatus.FORBIDDEN:
                raise e
            url = change_scheme(url)


with open('urls.txt', encoding='utf-8') as urls:
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        for _ in executor.map(do_get, urls):
            pass
```

There is no attempt in this code to download any content. This is just to demonstrate the importance of checking the HTTP response code

Comment: I will check status code, I should do it earlier. Thanks for pointing! But all the links are copied from FireFox tabs, 20-30 minutes before I started to write this script. Most should be fine, but as I see now, many of them produce 4xx status codes (404, 403, 400). Strange.

Comment: Try passing a User-Agent header. If they work in your browser then that's maybe all you need to do. That won't explain the 404 error though

Comment: Thanks for all suggestions!  404 I got rather rarely. I will modify my script and come back with better one. Thanks once again for help I got so far.

Comment: At least one of the URLs in your list generates a 403 status code. This is because it's using the HTTP scheme whereas the same URL for HTTPS works. I have edited to code so that it makes up to two attempts when the status is 403 by toggling the scheme